# Where is the correct place to insert odd snippets of configuration code in Ruby such as the config for awesome_print?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Sometimes I need to insert a chunk of code into a Rails app to perform some kind of config.  I seem to be missing something with regards to where this should go.  Let's say, for example, awesome_print.  I would like to eliminate it's color printing as I use it in logs and need this in `production` and `staging` only.

I've tried inserting it into `environment.rb`, `application.rb`, an initializer and such, yet none of these are appropriate.  They each result in various errors.

Where would insert a config line such as:

```
if RAILS_ENV == 'production'
  ap object, options = {:plain =>true}
if
```

Comment: For environment.rb I get: `undefined local variable or method \`object' for main:Object (NameError)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code example doesn't work because `object` is undefined. If you just want to set some defaults for the gem then you can create a file called `awesome_print.rb` in the initializers directory.

```
if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?
  AwesomePrint.defaults = {
    :plain => true
  }
end
```

See the 'Setting Custom Defaults' section on the github page: https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print

The linked section uses an `.aprc` file in the user's home directory but it should work the same with an initializer.

Comment: Okay thanks. That's perfect.  I thought that it should probably go into initializers, however yes, the problem was `object`.  Right, I've gotten settings from there.  Really appreciated.

Comment: Could you please explain or refer me also to more information regarding the `object` issue?  I would like to have a more core understanding of what's happening here.

Comment: `ap` just prints the result of its first argument. For example `ap [1, 2, 3]`, `ap 1 + 1`, etc. `ap object, options = {}` from the github page is just example code and not actual code that should be run.

Comment: Oh holy cow, I see what you're saying.  They're just saying `ap object_to_print`. LOL.